# QML: Set Property of Nested ListElement

Tags: qt, qml

I have a ListModel like the following:

```
ListModel {
  id: liveFeedModel

  ListElement {
    modelSrc: [
        ListElement { src: "../img/pano.jpg" },
        ListElement { src: "../img/pano1.jpg" },
        ListElement { src: "../img/pano2.jpg" },
        ListElement { src: "../img/pano3.jpg" }
    ]
    name: "Cookies"
    temp: "456 °C"
    time: "--:--"
  }

  ListElement {
    modelSrc: [
        ListElement { src: "../img/pano2.jpg" }
    ]
    name: "Sourdough Roll"
    temp: "123 °F"
    time: "--:--"
  }
}
```

And I would like to set the value of the nested ListElements within `modelSrc`.

I am looking for something similar to:

`liveFeedModel.get(0).modelSrc.get(2).src`

except with `set`, `setProperty`, or something along those lines, instead of `get`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
myListView.model.get(0).modelSrc.setProperty(0, "src", "../img/pano2.jpg");
```

simple as that!